# Bootstrap styling not applied in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-5, ng-bootstrap

I'm new to angular.
I tried to clone someone's project on github.

But when i run the apps, bootstrap components is there but without styling.
everytime i add another bootstrap component, the styling is not applied at all.

my clone app look like this:

[image: ()]

while the original look like this:

[image]

I don't do anything to files like app.module, angular.json, package.json etc. I just clone and run the app. Can someone explain what happened?

Comment: press F12 on the website and check the network tab and the console tab, see if any errors and share back on this question

Comment: no errors detected. all white

Comment: is it possible to share the clone link?

Comment: i clone this repo: https://github.com/rodrigokamada/angular-bootstrap

Comment: did you do the following steps, git clone -> npm i -> npm start ? its working fine for me?

Comment: yes. after cloning the repo I do the npm install, then ng serve to start the app